# whereBetween doesnt exist and i cant apply paginate

Tags: laravel, pagination, where-clause

I've this method:

```
   public function indexGuest($idAzienda, Request $request){

    $companyId = $idAzienda;
    $ddts = Ddt::where('company_id',$companyId);
    $ddt_urls= Ddt_file_url::all();

    if($request->start_date || $request->end_date){
        $ddts->whereBetween('created_at',[new Carbon($request->start_date),new Carbon($request->end_date)]);
    }
    $ddts->paginate(10);

    return view('guest.ddt-management')->with('ddts', $ddts)->with('ddt_urls',$ddt_urls)
        ->with('companyId',$companyId);


}
```

My `start_date` and `end_date` comes in strings like `"yyyy-mm-dd"`.
I've tried to pass it straight to the query and like in the example like a carbon object with no hope!

After executing the query (now only the one without the wherebeeteween clause) i cant apply the method "paginate" to the collection, no error are raised but when i pass it to the view, the "link()" method not work and raise an error again.
where I wrong?

Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure your `where`s like this.

```
public function indexGuest($idAzienda, Request $request) { 
    [...]
    $ddts = Ddt::where('company_id', $companyId)
        ->where(function($query) use ($request) {
            if($s = $request->get("start_date") {
                 $s_date = Carbon::parse($s)->format("Y-m-d");
                 $query->whereDate("created_at", ">=", $s_date);
            }
            if($e = $request->get("end_date") {
                 $e_date = Carbon::parse($e)->format("Y-m-d");
                 $query->whereDate("created_at", "<=", $e_date);
            }
        })
        ->paginate(10);     
    [...]
}
```

Comment: i take a while to understand... but it works! many thanks...where i wrong on my approach on paginate? thanks a lot!

Comment: Im really not sure what is causing the issue. Maybe try to use `toSql` instead of `paginate` then dump the result using `dd($ddts)` to see if the queries are different. Sorry, im on mobile now.